# How do I get Json data from Retrofit using Kotlin? (Android Studio)

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

Trying to wrap my head around Retrofit. I'm new to this so I find it confusing even though I have watched videos and read about it here on `SO`. I have added some `JSON` test data that looks like this:

```
[
    {"name":"John","age":30,"vehicle":"bicycle"}, 
    {"name":"Bob","age":32,"vehicle":"walking"}
]
```

It has been validated and is found on this adress: `https://api.myjson.com/bins/lnjb8`

Have added internet permission in `manifest` and `gradle` implementations.

My `interface` looks like this:

```
interface RetrofitCalls {

    @get:GET("lnjb8")
    val posts:Observable<List<RetrofitVariables>>
}
```

I have a class to deserialise the `Json` data in the `constructor`:

```
class RetrofitVariables(var name: String, var age: Int, var vehicle: String) {}
```

Then in my main class my builder looks like this:

```
var myRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

But from here I'm completely clueless on how to get the `Json` data. So my questions are, how do I use the interface to display the raw `Json` data (console is fine), and how do I deserialise the `Json` data?

***UPDATE***
I added this:
In the `interface`:

```
@GET("lnjb8")
fun findPosts(): Call<List<RetrofitVariables>>
```

And in `main` class:

```
var repository = myRetrofit.create(RetrofitCalls::class.java)

val jsonVariables = repository.findPosts().execute().body()

jsonVariables!!.forEach { println("TAG " + it) }
```

Is this correct? It keeps crashing, and I think it has to do with it being a synchronous call rather than an asynchronous call. I saw somewhere that it's possible to use `.enqueue()` as in `jasonVariables.enqueue()` but I'm unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right way, almost there. Now that you have the `myRetrofit`, you need to use it. You can use it by doing this:

```
val repository = myRetrofit.create(RetrofitCalls::class.java)
```

Once you have the `repository`, you can call the methods on it. You don't have any methods in your interface, so I'm not sure if your construct works. What works for me, is the following:

```
interface RetrofitCalls {
    @GET("lnjb8")
    fun findPosts(): Call<List<RetrofitVariables>>
}
```

I've used `Call`, but probably `Observable` works just as well if you want to do async calls.

If you want the full version of how to use the repository:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

data class RetrofitVariables(var name: String, var age: Int, var vehicle: String)

interface RetrofitCalls {
    @GET("lnjb8")
    fun findPosts(): Call<List<RetrofitVariables>>
}

var myRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

val repository = myRetrofit.create(RetrofitCalls::class.java)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val call = repository.findPosts()
    val variables = call.execute().body()

    variables?.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
RetrofitVariables(name=John, age=30, vehicle=bicycle)
RetrofitVariables(name=Bob, age=32, vehicle=walking)
```

Comment: Thanks you for helping me out @Erik! I tried your code but it keeps crashing. I think it has do do with synchronicity. Please see my updated post if there is some solution to this. Oddly, there's no error message...

Comment: Hi @tore , I've updated the example to be more complete. I've tried running, and it works for me.

Comment: I'm running it from `onCreate` on main thread. Perhaps that is why it keeps crashing, no? Error message: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.android.slothmode.jsonexexercise, PID: 5954
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.slothmode.jsonexexercise/com.android.slothmode.jsonexexercise.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException          

Are you calling `fun main(args: Array<String>)` from `onCreate`? What is that parameter `args` ? Think I'm missing something. Will play around a bit..